# Suggested Ways To Handle Meshes in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, mesh

I'm looking for better ways to handle having a mesh than my current implementation which is basically the .obj format in the form of a class.

My Current Structure is

```
Class Vertex
{
    float[3] Pos;
}

Class Face
{
    Vertex[3] Verts;
    float[3][3] Norm;
    float[3][3] Tex;
}

Class Mesh
{
    Face[] MeshData;
}
```

I can use this just fine in most cases,  but I'd like to be able to do things such as manipulate a vertex and move it randomly. I did it, however the connected faces wouldn't move with it.

That could probably be fixed by making all references to a vertex in the same position, a reference to the same vertex,  but I don't know how to do that beforehand and I can't imagine removing double vertices would be an even remotely fast operation with my setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be manipulating the mesh and rendering speed is secondary look into the [half-edge data structure](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml).

If rendering speed is paramount flatten everything out into a interleaved vertex/texcoord/normal array for maximum VA/VBO-friendliness:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float u, v;
    float nx, ny, ny;
};
```

Generally you'll want `sizeof(Vertex)` to be a multiple of 32 bytes.